# Removing Puncuation Marks off a text file and then calculating odd and even length words

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, bufferedreader

So far, i have done a lot in the code.. i replaced the punctuation marks from the text file but i do not know how to find the words with even and odd lengths and add them to their count. So: My wordcount for this file is 114 words but this program returns 50 even words and 55 odd words which doesn't add up to my wordcount of 114 so there is obviously something wrong.

Comment: I think you should put the System.out.println statement inside the while loop to display the counts after each line.  You may also need to post the contents of the file because it would be difficult to resolve this without it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       BufferedReader file3 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sonnet1-b.txt"));

        int even = 0;
        int odd = 0;
        String lines;
        String processedLine = "";
```

//It's unclear if this variable will have a bigger purpose in the future

```
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<>();

        while ((lines = file3.readLine()) != null) {
            processedLine = lines.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").replaceAll("( )+", " ");
```

//I removed words here and changed the split to split on the space.  When I ran your original code, the whole text came in as one line.  I think your original problem may have been in this area.  You need to get the length of the words.  You're original split param only put spaces into each.

```
            String[] each = processedLine.split(" ");
            for (String str1 : each) {
```

//Based on your description, you need to check the length of str1, not each.

```
                if (!(str1.length() % 2 == 0)) {
                    odd++;
                } else {
                    even++;
                }
            }
        }                               
        System.out.println("There were " + even + " even words, and " + odd + " odd words");
```

There were 58 even words, and 56 odd words

Comment: It's hard to understand what you think is the problem on the second text.  I suspect that the output counted more words than you expected.  The problem might be that world-without-end is being counted as 3 words.  SO...        processedLine = lines.replaceAll("'", "").replaceAll("-","").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").replaceAll("( )+", " ");